# Find the quadratic Taylor polynomial of erf about a=0?

Tags: taylor-expansion

[image]

The answers say that $P_3(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x^2 $

I understand that this is the sum of the first four terms, however I don't know how they calculated this.

I know that the formula for the Taylor polynomial is:

(https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=formula+taylor+polynomial&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoA2oVChMI07OV5NCDxgIVoyWmCh3q_wAy#imgrc=RotCLAuSvuCw1M%253A%3Bu4C42FgpnBrGaM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.stack.imgur.com%252FMAMOg.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmath.stackexchange.com%252Fquestions%252F883029%252Ftaylor-series-theorem%3B458%3B100)

However the integral in this question confuses me so I'm not sure how to calculate it.

Comment: The answer $P_3(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x^2$ doesn't look right ... erf(x) has value 0 at x=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take the derivative of a function defined by an integral, you use the fundamental theorem of calculus. In this case, it tells you that 
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2}
$$
so that 
$$
f'(0) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^0 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} 1.
$$
See whether you can work out $f''(0)$ and $f'''(0)$ for yourself.

As @grand_chat observes, the expression given is surely wrong, because the value at 0 should be 0, and the derivative there should be $2/\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: But what happens to the $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} $ ?

Comment: It got lost because I screwed up -- Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Expand $e^{-t^2}$ using the well-known Taylor series for the exponential function, and then reverse the order of summation and integration. [The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIT6e.png) confirms the suspicions of the other users.